# Conditional Probablity for two independent events(Formula)

Tags: probability, independence

Let there be two independent events $A$ and $B$. To calculate the probability (for a particular condition) we have two relations.

1. $P(A \cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cap B)$.
2. $P(A/B)P(B)=P(A \cap B)$, i.e., $P(A)P(B)=P(A \cap B)$.

But since the two events are independent,they can be expressed by a Venn diagram as two disjoint sets.

[image]

What I want to know, is the case that if the above said statement is true, then $P(A \cap B)=0$, and thus, is $P(A)P(B)=0$ (which is not true in this case)?

Or, can we deduce from 1. and 2., that,

$P(A)P(B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A \cup B)$?

If so, what are the specific conditions needed to fulfill the above relation? If not, what is conceptually wrong? Thanks for the help!

Formatting and other edits are welcome.

Comment: Being independent is *not* the same as being disjoint (or mutually exclusive) as you seem to think. $A$ and $B$ are independent iff $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$. $A$ and $B$ are disjoint if $A\cap B=\varnothing$.  Secondly (about 2.) $P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ is true by definition, but it is not the same as indepence as you seem to think. Statement 1 is always true.

Comment: so can we relate the two?(pardon me if you already answered that).

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Is the last relation in the the question a valid one?

Comment: It is valid if and only if $A$ and $B$ are independent. Then the statement 1 (always true) can be modified. We can replace $P(A\cap B)$ by $P(A)P(B)$ and the relation comes out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If two events are independent, it means that, by definition $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B) $, such that if $P(A) > 0$ and $P(B) > 0$ then $P(A\cap B) >0$. Alternatively, $P(A|B)=P(A)$, where $P(B)>0$. So, basically, your diagram is incorrect.

Assume for simplicity that $A\cup B = \Omega$ and $A\cap B = \emptyset$ and neither $B$ and $A$ are empty sets. I choose it because it resembles your initial construction. Note that in this case, $P(A|B)=0$ and $P(A|\bar{B})=1$, so, mutual disjoint sets, in this case, are dependent.  So, for two non empty sets $A$ and $B$ which designates two independent events, more appropriate Venn diagram would be with a nonempty intersection, $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$, which probability measure will satisfy $P(A)P(B)$.